# How to dynamically add a method to a class in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-runtime

I understand a major advantage of Objective-C over C++ is its ability to send messages to objects instead of calling its methods. Secondly you are allowed to dynamically add a method to objects.

Suppose this is my object:

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject
{}

- sayHello;

@end
```

I know my code below will work even if `- sayGoodbye` isn't defined, but can someone finish this code and demonstrate how Objective-C can add methods to objects at runtime?

```
MyClass* o = [[MyClass alloc] init];

[o sayHello  ];
[o sayGoodbye];
[o release   ];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The objective c runtime reference is what you need here:

[Objective-C Runtime Reference](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/objective-c_runtime?language=objc)

in particular look at the following method: [`class_addMethod`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/1418901-class_addmethod?language=objc)